# jQuery changed ID won't run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a blue div that turns red when clicking on it and the red div turns back to blue ( so I can add more events on the click after clicking, so .css isn't really an option)

When clicking on the div when it's blue, it turns red. But when I click the red div it doesn't respond, even when I add a simple alert()

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my current code and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FmSt/1/)

code:

```
$("#Blue").click(function(){
    $("#Blue").attr("id","Red");
});

$("#Red").click(function(){
    $("Red").attr("id","Blue");
});
```

If anyone could tell me what Exactly I'm doing wrong that would be great, thank you in advance

Comment: Why aren't you using `CSS` for this.. ie: Adding/Removing a class and referring to that class in your selector?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to change the `id` like this?  `id` is used to *identify* an element.  `style` is used to *style* an element.

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery `toggleClass()` documentation, probably your best bet.

Comment: @KristerAndersson simply using the *"on handler"* isn't enough to cause delegation to happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use **event delegation** -- your `click` handlers are bound to the matching elements at the time the code is first run, and only then. Since there's no `#Red` element at that point in time, that second click handler isn't bound to anything.

```
$(document).on('click',"#Blue", function(){
    $("#Blue").attr("id","Red");
});

$(document).on('click',"#Red", function(){
    $("#Red").attr("id","Blue");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/HDFyn/

http://api.jquery.com/on

---

That said, the "proper" way to do this would be to add and remove a class, not change the ID:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("red blue");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mKMW6/

Answer (score 2):

`.click()` binds only to existing elements at the time you call it; it will not bind to a later-created element or an element to which you assign the id later.

The fix is to use event delegation. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

Also, use classes, instead -- much more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div class="Test blue">Test</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".blue, .red").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red blue')
});
```

**CSS**

```
.Test{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FmSt/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the class and update the ID like below instead of having 2 function to do that action,

```
$('.Test').on('click', function () {
    this.id = (this.id == 'Blue')?'Red':'Blue';
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8FmSt/2/

If it is all about changing color, then use a css to change to color like below,

```
$('.Test').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('Red Blue');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8FmSt/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".Test").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id == "Red"){
        $(this).attr("id","Blue");
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr("id","Red");
    }   
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FmSt/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Let's uncomplicate

HTML

```
<div class="Test">Test</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".Test").on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

CSS

```
.Test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
```